# Is there an equivalent of the CTRL+. shortcut key in Excel 2016 and Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-365

It seems that this shortcut key was removed and I haven't been able to find a ribbon based replacement for it.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> is the [Move active cell clockwise in selection](https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts/move-active-cell-clockwise-in-selection) which is quite key for efficient range selection so not having this available in the latest versions of Excel is a major drawback.

Comment: I've never used that shortcut. You could probably map a macro that would do the same thing.

Comment: It works for me.  I have MS Professional Plus 2016 (2016 MSO (16.0.4738.10000 32-bit).

Comment: So I tried it now and initially found it works and was very confused. So what seems to be going on is that if you select and empty range then CTRL+. works as it used to. If you have contents in the cells then some new formatting table comes up which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that the "Quick Analysis options" popup was blocking this shortcut. The solution was to disable "Show Quick Analysis options on selection" under Options > General.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

With this change the shortcut key now works the same as in Excel 2010.

Comment: I have quick analysis enabled and I can still use `Ctrl+.` to move clockwise in the selection

Comment: Thands for the feedback @phuclv. If it causes a problem for me again on a new PC, I'll take another look. For now it's working for me.